# Can Credit Card autofill set card type fields?

Tags: html, safari, credit-card, autofill

A simple question about form autofill (in my specific case using Safari 9.1.1). As far as I read on the web, autofill can fill these fields:

```
<input type="text" id="cardNumber">
<input type="text" id="cardHolder">
<input type="text" id="cardExpirationMonth">
<input type="text" id="cardExpirationYear">
<input type="text" id="cardCsc”>
```

But can autofill also change the card type (the small radio buttons which select whether you have a VISA, Mastercard, VISA Electron, etc.)?

I am asking because I actually experienced on a website the fact that after autofilling the card number the card type changed on its own from VISA to VISA Electron. Was this triggered by autofill or by the web page code?

The html code of the radio buttons looks like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="cardType_18" class="paymentSubType cardTypeCode”
    name="cardModel.paymentObjectId" value="18">
```

Is there a way to actually see which information Safari stores (under preferences only card number and expiration date is displayed)?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the first six digits of the card number which is called the INN (issuer identification number). Based on that information you can see what the card type should be then update accordingly. [Here's the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number) that gives the INN ranges for various providers.